# Problema entre controles que estão acima do que gera evento Mouse Enter e Leave

Tags: c#

Boa Noite a todos.

Existe um controle panel no qual engatilha eventos quando o mouse entra e sai de sua região. Entretanto, existe também outros controles e estes estão em cima do panel em si, não engatilhando o evento.

Como posso continuar engatilhando os eventos mesmo com outros controles em cima? existe alguma forma?

Agradecido !

Comment: Que tipo de controlo é o painel? E os items são subitems do painel ou outros controlos?

Comment: Os itens são subitens do panel. Quando o mouse passa no panel, ele dispará os eventos normalmente, entretanto, quando passa em cima dos subitens, não engatilha os eventos até que saia de cima do panel.